# Windows UWP connect to BLE device after discovery

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, gatt

I'm using `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` to find nearby BLE devices and it's working well. After finding them I want to connect and read/write data via GATT. But I can't figure out how to use the API after getting the `BluetoothLEAdvertisement` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile).

```
public class Adapter
{
    private readonly BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher _bleWatcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();

    public Adapter()
    {
        _bleWatcher.Received += BleWatcherOnReceived;
    }

    private void BleWatcherOnReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs args)
    {       
        // how to connect?
        // I know, it's the wrong place to to this, but this is just an example
    }

    public void StartScanningForDevices(Guid[] serviceUuids)
    {
        _blewatcher.advertisementfilter.advertisement.serviceuuids.clear();
        foreach (var uuid in serviceuuids)
        {
            _blewatcher.advertisementfilter.advertisement.serviceuuids.add(uuid);
        }
        _blewatcher.start();
    }
}
```

I've found Samples that are using `DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync` instead of `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` but these are not working / finding any device.

**UPDATE**

After digging around some time, I found the following way. But unfortunately, the pairing fails. The device is just an Arduino with a BLE shield. I can definitely connect with Android and iOS. So it must be possible with UWP somehow. :/

```
private void BleWatcherOnReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs args)
{       
    var dev = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(args.BluetoothAddress);
    // dev.DeviceInformation.Pairing.CanPair is true
    // dpr.Status is Failed
    DevicePairingResult dpr = await dev.DeviceInformation.Pairing.PairAsync(DevicePairingProtectionLevel.None);
    var service = await GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync(dev.DeviceInformation.Id);
}
```

**UPDATE #2**

I'm now able to discover and pair (unstable, but ok for now), but

```
var service = await GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync(args.Id);
```

throws the following Exception

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
>   The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

I have no clue why.

Comment: Been wrestling with this too. I'm running Windows 10 IOT on a Raspberry Pi 2. My first issue was that I was missing the DeviceCapability tag in the appxmanifest. That wouldn't let me get a BluetoothLEDevice. After I fixed that I'm stuck at the same place you are (Update #2 above). I've tried pairing the device using code but that always fails. Pretty close to giving up myself.

Comment: The answer is pretty simple: YOU CAN'T!!!! Somehow, who implemented the API thought that is much better to pair the device first manually and then use it in your code... There are multiple examples and posts around the internet about this issue... Unfortunately, I've just finished writing a sample app using node.js on raspbian OS for Raspberry PI 3 and I just wanted to get to my master dev skills: C# and Windows but it seems that I have to go back to Linux :( The pairing and GATT discovery is made in 3 lines of code using node.js on Raspbian... A big shame for UWP 10 SDK. Sorry!

Comment: I have hit an issue with GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync on Windows 10 Creators Update - when used with classic desktop apps, it never returns. So beware that one, too

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**UPDATE 04/17 - CREATORS UPDATE**

Microsoft have just updated their Bluetooth APIs. We now have unpaired BLE device communication!

They have very little documentation up at the moment but here is the much simplified new structure:

```
BleWatcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher 
{ 
    ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active
};
BleWatcher.Start();

BleWatcher.Received += async (w, btAdv) => {
    var device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(btAdv.BluetoothAddress);
    Debug.WriteLine($"BLEWATCHER Found: {device.name}");

    // SERVICES!!
    var gatt = await device.GetGattServicesAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine($"{device.Name} Services: {gatt.Services.Count}, {gatt.Status}, {gatt.ProtocolError}");

    // CHARACTERISTICS!!
    var characs = await gatt.Services.Single(s => s.Uuid == SAMPLESERVICEUUID).GetCharacteristicsAsync();
    var charac = characs.Single(c => c.Uuid == SAMPLECHARACUUID);
    await charac.WriteValueAsync(SOMEDATA);
};
```

Much better now. As I said there is next to no documentation at the moment, I have a weird issue where my ValueChanged callback stops being called after 30 seconds or so, though that seems to be a separate scoping issue.

**UPDATE 2 - SOME WEIRDNESS**

After some more playing around with the new creators update there are a few more things to consider when building BLE apps.

- You no longer need to run the Bluetooth stuff on the UI thread. There doesn't seem to be any permissions windows for BLE without pairing so no longer necessary to run on UI thread.
- You may find that your application stops receiving updates from the device after a period of time. This is a scoping issue where objects are being disposed of that shouldn't. In the code above if you were listening to `ValueChanged` on the `charac` you may hit this issue. This is because the `GattCharacteristic` is disposed of before it should be, set the characteristic as a global rather than relying on it being copied in.
- Disconnecting seems to be a bit broken. Quitting an app does not terminate connections. As such make sure you use the `App.xml.cs` `OnSuspended` callback to terminate your connections. Otherwise you get in a bit of a weird state where Windows seems to maintain (and keep reading!!) the BLE connection.

Well it has its quirks but it works!

**OLD ANSWER**

Following on from Jason's correct answer about devices needing to be paired to have their services be discovered, here is some sample code to address this:

```
    private void SetupBluetooth()
    {
        Watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher { ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active };
        Watcher.Received += DeviceFound;

        DeviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher();
        DeviceWatcher.Added += DeviceAdded;
        DeviceWatcher.Updated += DeviceUpdated;

        StartScanning();
    }

    private void StartScanning()
    {
        Watcher.Start();
        DeviceWatcher.Start();
    }

    private void StopScanning()
    {
        Watcher.Stop();
        DeviceWatcher.Stop();
    }

    private async void DeviceFound(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs btAdv)
    {
        if (_devices.Contains(btAdv.Advertisement.LocalName))
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, async () =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"---------------------- {btAdv.Advertisement.LocalName} ----------------------");
                Debug.WriteLine($"Advertisement Data: {btAdv.Advertisement.ServiceUuids.Count}");
                var device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(btAdv.BluetoothAddress);
                var result = await device.DeviceInformation.Pairing.PairAsync(DevicePairingProtectionLevel.None);
                Debug.WriteLine($"Pairing Result: {result.Status}");
                Debug.WriteLine($"Connected Data: {device.GattServices.Count}");
            });
        }
    }

    private async void DeviceAdded(DeviceWatcher watcher, DeviceInformation device)
    {
        if (_devices.Contains(device.Name))
        {
            try
            {
                var service = await GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync(device.Id);
                Debug.WriteLine("Opened Service!!");
            }
            catch
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Failed to open service.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void DeviceUpdated(DeviceWatcher watcher, DeviceInformationUpdate update)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Device updated: {update.Id}");
    }
```

The key things to note here are:

- DeviceWatcher needs both Added and Updated properties set to work.
- You need to catch the exception FileNotFound which occurs when attempting to interrogate a service which is not paired, or not yet ready.

Comment: thank you for your answer, this helped a lot. I turned the devicewatcher part into an awaitable method. check my answer below

Comment: Thanks for the "Creators" update. On Creators, this new unpaired device communication code works perfect in a UWP app, but I am struggling to get it working in a Windows Desktop exe. Even my original code (similar to the original post) stopped working when running as a Desktop exe in Creators. I started a new question here about that http://stackoverflow.com/q/43568096/3187714

Comment: Check out this thread on the microsoft forums, there's bugs in the security around the Bluetooth APIs in the 15063 SDK that may be causing these issues: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58da3fdb-a0e1-4161-8af3-778b6839f4e1/bluetooth-bluetoothledevicefromidasync-does-not-complete-on-10015063?forum=wdk#ef927009-676c-47bb-8201-8a80d2323a7f

Comment: To "terminate your connections" are you just calling Dispose on the objects that have it, or is there a termination call I'm missing?

Comment: @dumbledad Sorry should have been clearer. I meant disconnect. For some reason Microsoft have called this `.Close()` on the device object.

Comment: I have tried using the old windows gatt api and the runtime one ("Creators update") and I get the problem of "object has been disposed", I understand that it is related to this point due to the second point mentioned in Update 2, but how should the feature be set as a global rather? Here is a post related to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67934095/trying-to-create-a-gatt-client-application-for-windows-c-that-doesnt-fail-whe

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE (5/5/16)**: The "Element Not Found" error issue seems to only happen when the bluetooth settings screen isn't open/scanning.  I don't remember that being the case before 10586.218 but I haven't checked.  Obviously, not every issue is fixed in the update.

**UPDATE (4/29/16)**: The 10586.218 windows update appears to have fixed the problem of pairing with a device that has never been paired to the machine (or phone) before.  The process I've outlined here and Gerard Wilkinson's sample code in his answer should work more consistently now.

If you are lucky enough to get this to work, it requires waiting a considerable amount of time for the driver to install.  I've done it by having both BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher and a DeviceWatcher running simultaneously.

Save the DeviceInformation from the BluetoothLEDevice that you get from FromBluetoothAddressAsync() then Dispose() the BluetoothLEDevice before initiating pairing.  This is important.  If you don't, it won't see the Gatt Services after pairing.

Then wait for the DeviceWatcher to see the paired device.  It can take minutes but you'll usually get it before the progress bar for device installation (in the Bluetooth control panel) gets to 100%.  If FromIdAsync still fails, it usually means there was a driver installation error.  You can unpair and then do the pairing process over again.  That usually works for me.

It's very unstable, though, and it seems to be dependent on which Bluetooth chipset and driver the machine has.  I often get an Element Not Found error with FromBluetoothAddress but if it gets past there, pairing usually works on the first or second try.

PairAsync and UnpairAsync also need to be posted to the UI thread.  If it isn't able to pop up a blue dialog asking for authorization, you'll get exceptions.  You can use Post() from a saved UI SynchronizationContext or  Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.RunAsync() with an async delegate to do this.

I've seen multiple posts from MS employees on the forums saying FromBluetoothAddressAsync() only works for paired devices.  This isn't the case but it is buggy and seems to work best if the device has been paired manually at least once in the past.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I have posed some sample code which will work for discovering BLE services.

Comment: I'm stuck on the "Element not found" exception; have you found a way around it?

Comment: "Save the DeviceInformation from the BluetoothLEDevice that you get from FromBluetoothAddressAsync() then Dispose() the BluetoothLEDevice before initiating pairing. This is important. If you don't, it won't see the Gatt Services after pairing."

This is the most critical part of this answer, IMO.

I was able to get it working without using the `DeviceWatcher`. Grab the  device's Id from the saved `DeviceInformation` and after pairing use `BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(id)`. You can then get to the GATT Services via the `BluetoothLEDevice` API. (Note: Windows 10 IoT Core - 10.0.14936.1000)

Answer (score 4):

Gerard Wilkinson's answer is correct. To make life easier, I turned it into an awaitable method using Reactive Extensions (). Any comments are welcome.

So once you found the device using the BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher and paired with it, you can use this to enable GATTServices.

```
private async Task<GattDeviceService> GetGATTServiceAsync(string deviceName)
{
  //devicewatcher is abused to trigger connection
  var deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(); //trick to enable GATT

  var addedSource = Observable.FromEventPattern(deviceWatcher, nameof(deviceWatcher.Added))
                              .Select(pattern => ((DeviceInformation)pattern.EventArgs));

  var updatedSource = Observable.FromEventPattern(deviceWatcher, nameof(deviceWatcher.Updated))
                                .Select(pattern =>
                                {
                                  var update = ((DeviceInformationUpdate)pattern.EventArgs);
                                  return Observable.FromAsync(() => DeviceInformation.CreateFromIdAsync(update.Id).AsTask());
                                }).Concat();

  var source = addedSource.Merge(updatedSource);
  source.Publish().Connect(); //make sure the event handlers are attached before starting the device watcher

  deviceWatcher.Start();

  var result = await source.Where(di =>  di.Name == deviceName)                                       //find the relevant device
                           .Select(di => Observable.FromAsync(() => GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync(di.Id).AsTask()))       //get all services from the device
                           .Concat()                                                                                      //necessary because of the async method in the previous statement
                           .Where(service => service.Uuid == SERVICE_UUID)                                                //get the service with the right UUID
                           .Retry()                                                                                       //GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync can throw exceptions
                           .FirstAsync();

  deviceWatcher.Stop();

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have the answer partly included in the questions. In essence you use the BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher for finding the devices only, basically they work just as beacons.

And you are not suppose to connect these devices by only using this API. To connect the devices you must use DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(), and to get it to show you any devices, you do need to pair them first.

Anyway, if you are interested on getting data from some specific BLE characteristics, you could try using [GattCharacteristicNotificationTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.gattcharacteristicnotificationtrigger), for full example & a bit of additional explanations [see my blog](http://www.drjukka.com/blog/wordpress/?p=167).

Comment: I have to admit that I have not tried pairing that way, but I'll be adding that in my rather long things to do list