# FromBluetoothAddressAsync IAsyncOperation does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' error

Tags: c#, bluetooth, async-await

I am working on a simple BLE UWP. I've been referring to "[Windows UWP connect to BLE device after discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420940/windows-uwp-connect-to-ble-device-after-discovery)", working in Visual Studio 2017.

The core code I have is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Threading;


using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;
using Windows.Devices;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher;

        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();

            watcher.Received += OnAdvertisementReceived;
        }

        private async void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var dev = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(eventArgs.BluetoothAddress);

            }


    }
```

In the line

```
var dev = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(eventArgs.BluetoothAddress)
```

it gives the error:

```
IAsyncOperation<Bluetooth> does not contain a definition for
'GetAwaiter' and the best extension method overload
'windowsRuntimeSystemExtensions.GetAwaiter(IAsyncAction)' requires a
receiver of type 'IAsyncAction'
```

I tried adding references to `System.Runtime`, `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime`, and `Windows` but this error still appears.

From my searching, the reason seems to be that the method `FromBluetoothAddressAsync` should return a Task.

From "[BluetoothLEDevice Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothLEDevice)", I can check that `FromBluetoothAddressAsync` method has this signature:

```
public static IAsyncOperation<BluetoothLEDevice> FromBluetoothAddressAsync(
    UInt64 bluetoothAddress,
    BluetoothAddressType bluetoothAddressType
)
```

which means that it returns `IAsyncOperation<BluetoothLEDevice>`. The way I see it, this seems enough to be recognized as something as a `Task<>`.

Is the problem due to a broken link which allows `IAsyncOperation<>` to be recognized as a child of `Task<>`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To await an `IAsyncOperation`, you need two things:

- A reference to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll`
- A reference to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Facade\Windows.WinMD`

If either reference is missing then it won't work. You can also use the [UwpDesktop](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UwpDesktop/) nuget package, that will do the work for you.

Note: specifically `GetAwaiter` is extension in `System` namespace that is available from those references (you still need `using System;` - make sure you have not removed it from the file). The extension info is on MSDN - [WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions.GetAwaiter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windowsruntimesystemextensions.getawaiter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions_GetAwaiter__1_Windows_Foundation_IAsyncOperation___0__).

Comment: thank you very much. 'UwpDesktop' solution worked for me.. now a different error pops up, but at least the await error doesn't show up.

Comment: I'm afraid that with  build 15063 code never gets past the call to ```BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync```

Comment: The Another aswer is a real answer

Comment: [System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime/) nuget package worked in my end.

Comment: System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime did the trick! Thanks

Answer (score 22):

For some of the other UWP operations just add `using System`:

```
using System;

//...

// example - getting file reference:
var file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("myFile.txt);
```

Answer (score 1):

For a '.NET Standard 2.0' Library project, add these Nugets:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts