# Create file in StorageFolder

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm new in UWP application development and I want to create folder using LocalStorage so I have something like:

```
private static StorageFolder _settingsFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

public async static Task<bool> SaveUsers(string file, List<mymodel> data)
    {
        try
        {

            StorageFile currentFile = await _settingsFolder.CreateFileAsync("myfile.json", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

 
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

but it just throw an error:

> 'IAsyncOperation' does not contain a definition for
> 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first
> argument of type 'IAsyncOperation' could be found (are
> you missing a using directive for 'System'?)

I read another questions about `GetAwaiter` issue but I can not found a fix to this. Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FromBluetoothAddressAsync IAsyncOperation does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099401/frombluetoothaddressasync-iasyncoperation-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-get)

Comment: Hello, your code looks ok. Are you missing the necessary references? You can delete the `bin` and `obj` folders in the project and rebuild the project

Comment: Are you sure that this error refers to that piece of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write `using System;` at the the top of the file.