# How to call WinRT from MAUI code-behind in the right thread?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, maui

I am trying to use a [`GraphicsCapturePicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture.graphicscapturepicker?view=winrt-20348) from the code-behind in a `MAUI` app and am hitting a COM exception implying I am calling this from the wrong thread. Typically code in WPF/XAML code-behind files are dispatched from the main thread so I am a bit confused about what's going wrong here:

```
// A regular button event handler in MainPage.xaml.cs
private void OnScreenCaptureClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var picker = new GraphicsCapturePicker();
    GraphicsCaptureItem item = picker.PickSingleItemAsync().GetResults();
}
```

Throws exception:

```
"The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread"
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

Note: In the above example I am calling the method syncronously as a test to make it easier to catch the exception, the same thing happens when it's wrapped in a task.

This exact code works fine in a regular non-MAUI UWP/C# project.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with 'wrapped in a task' means. Async methods should in general be [awaited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099401/frombluetoothaddressasync-iasyncoperation-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-get/44102996#44102996). Also, as far as I can tell, MAUI is still in preview, so bugs might be expected.